# iOS11 scroll offset - problems with transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios11

I am working on an app where after iOS 11 a custom flip-card transition is not working correctly. If you look at the GIF below (purposely slow animation) you can see that the card is not correctly placed on the return-flip, and afterwards "clicks" into place. With iOS 10 and below this doesn't happen. It returns to its original place without the click.

[image: GIF of animation]

I have looked into the new contentInsetAdjustmentBehaviour and set this to .never to avoid the space between the cards and status bar on top. This however did not solve the problem.

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of where I should look to fix this problem?

**UPDATE HACK**

I looked at the transition and where the center of the transition is determined. Here I made a small hack for iOS 11 that moved the center 64 points for iPhone 8+ and below and 88 points for iPhone X. But only when I had not started scrolling yet. If I scrolled the center was moved 44 points on all iPhone models. See temporary solution below:

```
CGPoint targetCenterInContainer = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(newCardFrame), CGRectGetMidY(newCardFrame));

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

    double offset = newCardFrame.origin.y - originalCardFrame.origin.y;

    if (offset == 64) {
        targetCenterInContainer.y -= 64; // For iPhone 8 Plus and below, with no scroll offset
    } else if (offset == 88) {
        targetCenterInContainer.y -= 88; // For iPhone X, with no scroll offset
    } else {
        targetCenterInContainer.y -= 44; // For when there are scroll offset, all iPhones
    }
}
```

This works okay, but not 100%.

Comment: I would check the custom transition. How is the target rect calculated?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Looked at where the center of the view is determined and there I move the center 64 points up for iOS 11.

Comment: I'm currently battling with a strange contentOffset value on the iPhone X. I'm expecting 64 but am getting 88. I wonder if this has to do with the status bar height on the iPhone X. On the iPhone 7 the status bar height is 20, on the iPhone X the status bar height is 44. (44-20=24 and 88-64=24)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar problems with all animations from my app, some components after transitions are misplaced, so my recommendation it's just disable animations for ios 11 version I mean put animated value to false until apple fix all this problems.